# How do I use carrierwave in Rails without a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I simply want a form where a user chooses an image and it gets submitted to AWS S3..

This is the page where my form is

```
<%= form_tag('process', multipart: true) do %>
  <p>
    <label>My Image</label>
    <%= file_field :AssetImage %>
    <%= submit_tag "Send!" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the error wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) for file_field..

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'asdf',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'asdf',                            # required
    :host                   => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'AssetImage'                     # required
  config.fog_public     = true                                   # optional, defaults to     true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

that's my config and in the uploader i have storage :fog set. I don't understand!! I don't want it associated with anything.. I just want it to upload

Comment: are you using the fog gem?

Comment: so you'll upload then you wont know to what the file is associated?

Comment: why not but at least create an `upload` model

Comment: Once it's uploaded to S3 all I need is the URL for it so I can submit that to an API I am working with. And yeah I have the fog gem installed

Comment: @user7954 I don't think that is possible I would suggest rather use Fog gem directly to achieve the same without the use of carrierwave